# Asymptotes cuts curve in eight points which lie on a circle of radius unity

Tags: asymptotics

Show that the four asymptotes of the curve $(x^2-y^2)(y^2-4x^2)+6x^3-5x^2y-3x^2y+2y^3-x^2+3xy-1=0$ cut the curve again in eight points which lie on a circle of radius unity.

I have found the asymptotes to be $y=x; y=-x-1; y=2x; y=-2x-1$. 
Then I found the combined equation of the 4 asymptotes : $(x^2-y^2)(y^2-4x^2)-3x^2y+xy^2+4x^3+y^2-3xy=0$

To find points of intersection I subtracted combined equation of asymptotes from equation of curve, but it does not give equation of unit circle.
What am I missing? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

To find the intersections of the asymptotes and the curve you need to solve the equations simultaneously.  Those will give the common points.  Taking your first asymptote $y=x$ the first product is zero and we need to solve $$6x^3-5x^2y-3x^2y+2y^3-x^2+3xy-1=0\\$$  All the third power terms cancel and we are left with $$2x^2-1=0\\x=\frac {\sqrt 2}2=y$$
That is one point of intersection.  Go through your asymptotes.  Each one will reduce the curve equation to an equation in one variable.  Solve each one.  You should find a total of eight solutions.

Comment: That was easy! Thanks a lot!